# How do I check the value of a Boolean field in a template file?

Tags: theming, paragraphs

I have a paragraph with a boolean field.

- content type
- -paragraph entity reference
- left hand side paragraph
- checkbox
- image
- title

All the other fields have their own field-paragraph-field-checkbox.html.twig files and there's nothing to be checked, just adding a class around the image and title `{{ item.content }}` value.

However, I need to check if the checkbox field value is 1 or 0 in field-paragraph-field-checkbox.html.twig, and add a class if it's 1, or do nothing if it's 0.

When I tried printing the value with `{{ content.field_checkbox.value }}` nothing prints. I also tried with `{{ node.field_checkbox.value }}`, but I don't get any value.

How do I check the value of a Boolean field in a template file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how you debug but I think from question contest that trying  `node.field_checkbox.0.value` might work. Or if you are working with views and use `views_get_view_results` function, try `content._entity.field_checkbox.value` or `content._entity.field_checkbox.0.value` `0` used if field is untranslated

Update for comment:

```
function TEMPLATE_theme_suggestions_page_alter(&$suggestions, $variables) {

  // Check it's a node page.
  if (($node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node')) && $node instanceof \Drupal\node\NodeInterface) {
    array_splice($suggestions, count($suggestions) - 1, 0, 'page__node__' . $node->getType());
  }
}
```

with this code in your TEMPLATE.theme file drupal 8 suggest `page--node--CONTENT-TYPE-MACHINE-NAME.html.twig` (Undersores to dushes). and thats it, You might have `{{ kint(node) }}` or `{{ dump(node) }}` in your twig.

Comment: Hi Alen, tries that in the node.html.twig and field-paragraph-field-checkbox.html.twig files its blank. please see the updated field.html.twig file name maybe that might be the issue, really not sure

Comment: Thus I think you need to suggest the right twig file for your node. Or enable twig debugging to see suggestions in html comments

Comment: I have debug on, and for node template i am using the following. node--home-page.html.twig, which just prints {{ content }} and then for the field template using the field-paragraph-field-checkbox.html.twig

Comment: Hi Alen, i had already added template suggestions in my .theme so page--front.html.twig has {{ page.content }} and  node--home-page.html.twig has {{ content }}. kint and debug just keep my site loading nothing prints when i ckear cache and refresh the page

Comment: @Lloyd_07 can you kint $suggestions array in your _theme_suggestions_page_alter

Comment: i have managed to {{ dump(node) }} i can see the field block which has the referencing paragraph and checkbox field. please see the image screenshot [link]https://ibb.co/bPQeJo

Comment: So. lastly, can you get the checkbox field vaue? {{ dump(node.field_checkbox.value) }}

Comment: Still blank, will try something and revert back, just want to double check rendering paragraphs fields, within paragraphs, hope that makes sense...

Comment: hi @Alen, sorry for asking this so late, got busy with something else yesterday, now I am back on this task again. so what i notice is there are four paragraph types in the cms 1. grid layout, 2. content to include(CTI, which has image, title and link) 3. left hand side content(LHSC) 3. right hand side content(RHSC) -> grid layout has CTI paragraph which have then has the field field_checkbox. In the cms the admin must be able to add a new grid and add content to the RHS or LHS  the field_checkbox is used to check if there multiple in either RHSC or LHSC add a flex row.

Comment: Please sorry for very late reply, but if you don't find solution, I think this module can help you with.
https://www.drupal.org/project/twig_field_value

Comment: hi Alen, thanks i stumbled across this module and it worked wonders. Thanks for the replies they helped alot.